# Is the matrix representation of a multivariate normal unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

Under this definition of multivariate normal,
[image]

Is the matrix and mean tuple $(D, \mu)$ unique? Any proof?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. The covariance of $X$ in this case would be (easy to show)
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top]=DD^\top =:\Sigma.
$$
Now $\Sigma$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and the decomposition $\Sigma =D D^\top$ is in general not unique, unless you require on top that $D$ is positive semidefinite, too (like Cholesky).

Answer (score 0):

The vector $\mu$ is unique, since it must just be the expected value of $X$ (since $E(DW)=DE(W)=0$ no matter what $D$ is).  However, $D$ is not unique (unless the dimension is $0$).  The simplest way to see this is to consider when the distribution of $X$ is already standard normal.  Then $-X$ is also standard normal, so $D$ could be either the identity matrix $I$ or $-I$.  More generally, $D$ could be any orthogonal matrix, since the multivariate standard normal distribution is invariant under orthogonal transformations.